# MVC - display image from sqlite db

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

how can i export an image from DB - Sqlite and display this image in the view?
im using angular code, and the images byte stored now in x.img var.
i want to display the image in img tag.
i tried few ways...
please your help.

```
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <link href="~/Content/productmenuStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module("myCode", []);

        app.controller("CodeController", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.Table = false;

            $scope.showProduct = function (num) {
                $scope.number = num;
                $scope.getProduct(num);
            }

            $scope.getProduct = function (num) {
                var list = $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'getProductjson',
                    params: {
                        prClass: num
                    }
                });
                list.then(function (list) {
                    $scope.Products = list.data;
                }, function () {
                    alert("Inavalid data !!!");
                });
            }

            $scope.sendProduct = function (num) {
                var list = $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'sendProduct',
                    params: {
                        pid: num,
                    }
                });
                list.then(function (list) {
                    alert("The Product Addad To The Cart");
                }, function () {
                    alert("Inavalid data !!!");
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to reference images as a fixed url resource on the server, like img tag is normally used.
```<img  src="/image/6516543.gif"> ```

Comment: im getting bytes.. "img src="����ExifII*��Duckyd��Adobed����������� "

Comment: <td>
                        <font face="Arial black" size="3" color="black">
                            <img src="{{ x.img }}" alt="" height=300 width=300></img>
                        </font>
                    </td>

Comment: Is the image a string path or a binary image

Comment: Binary ... there is any solution?

Comment: The easiest solution is to **not** use binary images, since it's more difficult to get right, but instead use a URL path to the image. That means that you shouldn't store images as raw data in you SQLite database, but rather store images as string paths to your actual image files. Like so:   ["/images/image_of_food.jpeg", "/images/image_of_location.jpeg"  ], and then send the right imagepath to your client app.